# Spring 3.2.3 Release Java Config for Freemarker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker, spring-java-config

I was using Spring 3.1x and below is the code how I used to set freemarker properties in my config class

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig {

@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer fmc = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    FreeMarkerConfigurer
    fmc.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
    return fmc;
}

@Bean(name = DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver fvr = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    fvr.setCache(false);
    fvr.setPrefix("");
    fvr.setSuffix(".ftl");
    fvr.setRequestContextAttribute("rc");
    return fvr;
}

}
```

Now I upgrade my spring to 3.2.3 release and it's telling

> The method setTemplateLoaderPath(String) is undefined for the type
>   MvcConfig

How to set freemarker view path in spring 3.2.3 using java config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra "FreeMarkerConfigurer" line in your code above (unless that's just a copy/paste error). Can you post the full error message?

You may also need to add the spring-context-support JAR to your project. Here's the Maven pom.xml entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes JQ I have added spring-context-support jar file and it solve my problem.thanks alot